# C program in NetBeans -- debugger or run is not stopping, without a crash or error message

Tags: c, netbeans

I am using NetBeans in my C program, and when I try to allocate memory for a three dimensional array, the program just stops: nothing happens, netbeans doesn't react any more, but there is no error message.

The code is like this, the numbers are set during the runtime:

```
int ***my_matrix, i;
my_matrix = malloc(sizeof(int**)*1);
my_matrix[0] = malloc(sizeof(int*)*45169);
for(i=0; i < 45169; i++) {
   my_matrix[0][i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*43604);
}
```

After the for loop nothing happens any more.

Is this a memory problem? I already increased the heap space in NetBeans in the `netbeans.conf` file with adding the argument *(and restarted NetBeans)*:

> -J-Xmx2048m

in the netbeans_default_options part.

I have no idea what to do, or where the problem could be.

My operation system is OS X, and NetBeans is version 8.0

Comment: Can you compile it in the terminal?  Maybe you're getting something like a bus error that's not being reported in NetBeans but would in the terminal.

Comment: It might be a good idea to test the same code with much smaller constants (for example, 4 instead of 45169 and so on).

Comment: sizeof(int)*43604*45169=sizeof(int)*1878MB. check return value of malloc.

Comment: I already tested the program with smaller constants and it is working, so it has to be something with the size of them :S..not a logical error

Ok I will try to run in the terminal. DO i have to run make in this case :S, or just run my main.c file

Comment: @malajedala, it is important information, so it is better to include it in question.

Comment: `make main` should do it (to compile main.c), perhaps something like `CFLAGS='-std=c99' make main` (if you use C99 features and your compiler defaults to another standard, like e.g. gcc).

Comment: 2048 Mb is not enough for this array, because there are memory blocks limits. Try to increase heap space more (about 1.5 times I expect).

Comment: Ok there was no bus error or something, I guess it is an memory error so I will increase the space like IIya suggested. Is there an overall limit or can I put for example 2 GB of heap space ?

Comment: It's a memory allocation problem. Remember that your OS can only allocate certain amount of memory for each program with an absolute maximum limit for a running programme.